# Using AngularJs ngGrid with groups of nested json arrays

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have managed to do this with ngRepeat but am having a problem doing this with ngGrid. And none of the answers I've seen come close to touching this. 
The json looks something like this:

```
{
    "thing": "value",
    "thing2": "value",
    "ObjectArray": [
        {
            "thing": "value",
            "SubObject": {
                "thing": "value",
                "thing2": "value",
                "thing3": "value",
                "thing4": "value"
            },
            "SubObjectArray": [
                {object1},
                {object2},
                {object3}
            ],
            "thing2": "value",
            "thing3": "value"
        },
        {"Next object like the last"},...
    ]
}
```

In an ngRepeat I can create a table based on the objects contained within the ObjectArray that then repeats for the SubObjectArray (each object is a group each SubObjectArray is a member of that group and needs to be displayed under that group). However in an ngGrid the only way I seem to be able to access the SubObjectArray is by `ObjectArray.SubObjectArray[index#].thing`

I either need something that I'm not seeing in ngGrid to iterate over the array or need a way to tell it to iterate over the array.

Comment: did you try to use ngrepeat in cellTemplate ?

Comment: I have not tried the cellTemplate, though that is a good idea. I haven't found any suggestions around but it seems that the best idea is to return the data in a format that ng-grid can use by default. Either have the server return it correctly or use javascript after receiving, iterate the object and reformat on the fly. (as long as the object is not too large javascript client-side is fine)